# Need Help Finishing Inductive Proof Containing Subscripts

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The Proposition is as follows: Construct a sequence of numbers a<sub>1</sub> , a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>4</sub> as follows. Set a<sub>1</sub> = 5 then triple each term of the sequence and subtract four to obtain the next term. Prove the n<sup>th</sup> term is given by the forumula a<sub>n</sub> = 3<sup>n</sup> + 2.

***MY WORK SO FAR:***
I wrote out some of the sequence: 5, 11, 29, 83
I then created the following statement: S<sub>n</sub> = 5, 11, 29, 83... 3 (a<sub>n - 1</sub>) - 4 = 3<sup>n</sup> + 2 ; as long as n >= 2.

Base Case: n = 2, in the left hand side we get 11 and in the right hand side we get 11.

Inductive Step:
fix k: S<sub>k</sub> = 5, 11, 29, 83... 3 (a<sub>k - 1</sub>) - 4 = 3<sup>k</sup> + 2

S<sub>k+1</sub> = 3(<sub>a<sub>k + 1 - 1</sub></sub>) - 4 = 3<sup>k + 1</sup> + 2.

I then tried to put it into the following equation S<sub>k</sub> + a<sub>k</sub> = S<sub>k + 1</sub> But I never can get it to properly equal one another.

All Help would be much appreciated as I'm not looking for a direct answer, rather a helpful explanation and hints towards a correct answer.

**Again I am not looking for direct answers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is all about the sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots .$
There is no mention of taking any sum of these terms;
only a rule so that if you know one of the terms (such as $a_{15}$) you can compute the next term (so if you know $a_{15}$ you can compute $a_{16}$).

When they write, "Prove the $n$th term is given by ...," they mean "prove that $a_n$ is ... ."

For example, the first term is $a_1 = 5,$ 
and indeed when $n = 1$ we see that $$3^n + 2 = 3^1 + 2 = 3 + 2 = 5.$$

But if $n = 2$ then $$3^n + 2 = 3^2 + 2 = 9 + 2 = 11,$$ which we see is the second term of the sequence.
And if $n = 3$ then $$3^n + 2 = 3^3 + 2 = 27 + 2 = 29,$$
which is the third term.

If you try to prove that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $3^n + 2,$ you will not succeed, because that theorem is false.

The statement we are actually supposed to prove is that $a_n = 3^n + 2.$
Notice we have already shown it to be true for $n = 1,$ so you can use $n = 1$ rather than $n = 2$ for your base case.
For the inductive case you will only need to look at $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}.$

Answer (score 1):

"Set a1 = 5 then triple each term of the sequence and subtract four to obtain the next term."  So $a_1= 5$ and $a_{n+1}= 3a_n- 4$.  You want to use induction to prove that $a_n= 3^n+ 2$.  When n= 1, $a_1= 3^1+ 2= 3+ 2= 5$ is true.

Now the induction step:  Suppose that, for some k, $a_k= 3^k+ 2$.  Then $a_{k+1}= 3a_k- 4= 3(3^k+ 2)- 4= 3^{k+1}+ 6- 4= 3^{k+1}+ 2$. QED.

Comment: I am having a hard time following what you did specifically and why you did it. I understand that ak = 3^k + 2 but the parts after that are not so clear to me.

Comment: You were told that $a_{k+1}= 3a_k- 4$, right?  So if $a_k= 3^k+ 2$ then $a_{k+1}= 3(3^k+ 2)- 4= 3(3^k)+ 3(2)- 4= 3^{k+1}+ 6- 4= 3^{k+1}+ 2$.